# How to create Range Slider function like this?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

I am a beginner in React. I would like to learn more knowledge about setstate in react.
So, I tried to Create a Range Slider with these conditions.

• The value of Min cannot be changed to the Max value.[Sliders can originally be moved from Min to Max.]

• The value of the Range Slider is between 0.00 - 10.00 [2 decimal places].

What should I do to make it possible?

My code right now is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 300,
  },
});

function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}°C`;
}

export default function RangeSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([4, 7]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    
    <div className={classes.root}>
      
      <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        Temperature range
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        min={0}
        max={10}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        aria-labelledby="range-slider"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </div>
      
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "The value of Min cannot be changed to the Max value.[Sliders can originally be moved from Min to Max.]" Provide an example of what should not be possible

Comment: The `min` and `max` attribute values of a ranged input generally are not changed/updated while being used, but perhaps we've misunderstood you.

Comment: Why are you using React.useState with an array of 2 values? I think you should initialize it with just one value (without an array). Like: React.useState(4) if you want to have a start value of 4.